# How do I make the Google Chrome flag “--allow-file-access-from-files” permanent?

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, file-sharing

> " google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files "

Like i have an app,that requires chrome to have this **security restriction** on local files **removed.**
So i cant type do this everytime i take the app.

Any ideas?

PS: It would be great if you can tell what the **positives** and **negatives** about it,as well as **how to revert back** if needed.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Operating System (specifically UBUNTU)

Slightly Permanent Method

- Go to the menu entry/ launcher for Chrome (.desktop file)
- Open the launcher properties dialog.
- It should look something like this: ‘/usr/bin/google-chrome %U’
- Change it to ‘/usr/bin/google-chrome --allow-access-from-files‘ to
  make the flags work permanently

  You may also need to delete and re-pin your launcher(s) after
  modifying it. Chrome should launch with the specified flags enabled
  after the modification.

**PS: I found this [here](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/), haven't tried this out..**

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/192996#192996